Vampire Lord Transformation Crash to Desktop
Because of the problems with my old Skyrim game, I had no choice but to start a new game.
To make a long story short I began the Dawnguard quest and arrived at the part of the quest where Harkon turns me into a vampire.
After we go into the cathedral, He tells me to take the mantle of the Vampire Lord.
When I press the button the animation begins, freezes, and then crashes to the desktop.
This also happened in my old game.
How can I fix this?

Are you on PC? Console? (Via Steam? With mods?)

If no mods: Sounds like data corruption. Steam can fix it, and some other platforms will offer similar functionality. If your platform does not have some sort of "verify/repair" button, you may have to uninstall and reinstall.

Yes I am on PC.
I had to start the whole game over because of other issues.
I haven't installed ANY other mods since.
Only when I was told by Harkon to take on the mantle of the vampire Lord and I obey and do it, in the first burst as he is transforming the game freezes and thereafter crashes to the desktop.
I even tried to console command that part of the quest to be finished. "setstage DLC1VQ02 180"
It didn't work.
Though the next quest started with me having to see Garan Marethi to the seek out the blood chalice, Harkon was still telling me to transform.
I am stuck, dude!!!

Have you tried verifying/repairing your installation as Kevin suggested?

How do I do that?
Is that done through Steam?
Is that it in the following image?
[img]https://i.imgur.com/rNFghiD.png[/img]

@ZadekielSephirah: Yes, the instructions I linked to have a very similar screenshot.

Hey guys!
It's fixed.
After Verifying I had to download AE skse and then downgrade.
I can transform now.
Thank you for your help.
